# Input PHP into an JSON file

Tags: php, json

I am very new to web development. I have some JSON in a PHP file in the code below. I want to add PHP into this file. Every time I do the JSON doesn't work. The app that I am pulling the json from crashes. So how would I add my PHP code to this?

```
    [
   {
        "GAME1":"North Carolina @ South Carolina",
        "INFO1":"6:00PM Thursday, September 3",

        "GAME2":"Western Kentucky @ Vanderbilt",
        "INFO2":"8:00PM Thursday, September 3",

        "GAME3":"Tennessee-Martin - #17 Ole Miss",
        "INFO3":"12:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME4":"Louisiana Monroe @ #9 Georgia",
        "INFO4":"12:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME5":"UTEP @ #18 Arkansas",
        "INFO5":"3:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME6":"Louisville @ #6 Auburn",
        "INFO6":"3:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME7":"Bowling Green @ #25 Tennessee",
        "INFO7":"4:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME8":"Southeast Missouri State @ #24 Missouri",
        "INFO8":"4:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME9":"Louisiana Lafayette @ Kentucky",
        "INFO9":"7:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME10":"#15 Arizona State @ Texas A&M",
        "INFO10":"7:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME11":"New Mexico State @ Florida",
        "INFO11":"7:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME12":"McNees State @ #14 LSU",
        "INFO12":"7:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME13":"#20 Wisconsin @ #3 Alabama",
        "INFO13":"8:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME14":"Mississippi State @ Southern Mississippi",
        "INFO14":"10:00PM Saturday, September 5",


    }
]
```

Comment: add php into this file? what are you looking to do with this json file. And what would want to achieve by putting php in the file

Comment: I have a PHP file pulling scores from ESPN. I need to put the ESPN scoring data in "INFO#".

Comment: so you want the json file to look like this

`"GAME1":"Carolina","INFO1":"6:00PM ..","SCORE1":"xxx"`

Comment: The PHP that I have will update the score. Ex. ("INFO1":"UNC 7 USC 6"). I need to get my PHP code in INFO1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to add data to the JSON file.

To do that you need to open the file in php, parse the content, make your changes and save the file again.

I suggest you have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Answer (score 0):

You can store your json in a separate json file. Just create a .json file, say `scores.json` and then call it in a php file. So, something like this:

Your `score.json` file:

```
[
   {
        "GAME1":"North Carolina @ South Carolina",
        "INFO1":"6:00PM Thursday, September 3",

        "GAME2":"Western Kentucky @ Vanderbilt",
        "INFO2":"8:00PM Thursday, September 3",

        "GAME3":"Tennessee-Martin - #17 Ole Miss",
        "INFO3":"12:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME4":"Louisiana Monroe @ #9 Georgia",
        "INFO4":"12:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME5":"UTEP @ #18 Arkansas",
        "INFO5":"3:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME6":"Louisville @ #6 Auburn",
        "INFO6":"3:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME7":"Bowling Green @ #25 Tennessee",
        "INFO7":"4:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME8":"Southeast Missouri State @ #24 Missouri",
        "INFO8":"4:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME9":"Louisiana Lafayette @ Kentucky",
        "INFO9":"7:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME10":"#15 Arizona State @ Texas A&M",
        "INFO10":"7:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME11":"New Mexico State @ Florida",
        "INFO11":"7:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME12":"McNees State @ #14 LSU",
        "INFO12":"7:30PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME13":"#20 Wisconsin @ #3 Alabama",
        "INFO13":"8:00PM Saturday, September 5",

        "GAME14":"Mississippi State @ Southern Mississippi",
        "INFO14":"10:00PM Saturday, September 5",


    }
]
```

and then create a php file say, `testing.php`.
Your `testing.php` file:

```
<?php
$score = file_get_contents("/path/to/score.json");
$jsonRes = json_decode($score, true);
var_dump($jsonRes);
?>
```

Comment: Yes. But I need to put PHP data in the "INFO".